# SQL LAG function with JOIN - must pull data from previous row even if data is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have three tables:

1) `Calendar`

- This table has a single entry for each date (this is actually part of a larger table with daily records - I'm simplifying for this context)

2) `Reading_Type`

- `Reading_Type_ID`
- `Type_Name`

3) `Readings`

- `Reading_ID`
- `Reading_Type_ID`
- `Reading_Date`
- `Reading`

Only one entry is allowed for a given `Reading_Type_ID` and `Reading_Date`, but not all dates have a reading.

I need a query that returns all data from `Readings`, plus yesterday's reading for that `Reading_Type_ID`.

If the previous day (yesterday) has no reading, `Yesterday_Reading` should be 0 (it should *not* just pull the reading from the previous row in the table if that row is > 1 day prior).

What I have so far:

```
SELECT
      r.Reading_ID
    , r.Reading_Type_ID
    , r.Reading
    , r.Reading_Date
    , LAG(r.Reading, 1, 0)
        OVER (PARTITION BY r.Reading_Type_ID ORDER BY r.Reading_Date)
        AS Yesterday_Reading
FROM
    Calendar c
LEFT JOIN
    Readings r ON c.Date = r.Reading_Date
```

This LAG function pulls from the last row (by date) in the `Readings` table, not strictly from "yesterday".  I've tried some permutations (`ORDER BY c.Date`, adding rows from `c` to the `SELECT` clause, etc), but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: firstly there is no need of calender table in this requirement.Throw some sample data.I think recursive CTE is the best answer if expected number of rows are not more than 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need the full calendar period for each `Reading_Type_ID`.  You can do this using a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT r.Reading_ID, rr.Reading_Type_ID, r.Reading, r.Reading_Date,
       LAG(r.Reading, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY rr.Reading_Type_ID ORDER BY r.Reading_Date
                                 ) as Yesterday_Reading
FROM Calendar c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT r.Reading_Type_ID FROM Readings r) rr LEFT JOIN
     Readings r
     ON c.Date = r.Reading_Date AND r.Reading_Type_ID = rr.Reading_Type_ID;
```